# Google images view mode example

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to implement a google images kind of view of images(and other details) on click.

When a image is clicked, additional data expands under it with a arrow pointing to the starting position and when an other image is selected the first one collapses and the other expands. Does something like that exists(open source) or is there only the option to implement it myself?

Screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything ??

Comment: Did this work out for you??

Answer (score 0):

**Photoswipe** is a great responsive javascript library.

[This is a link to an example of Photoswipe.](http://photoswipe.com/)

You can add caption, customize backgrounds very similar to google image search. [image]

Once you click on the photo Photoswipe will let you display your images on your page using standard html, css and javascript. You can add captions as you see below.

[image]

[Attached Detailed Guide for Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html)

Comment: Let me know if you would like another product that has similar features.